# What does eating soup do to me?

Tags: grim-dawn

I've found Ulgrim, a cook and got him to join me in town. As a thank he makes soup, I've eaten a portion of his soup, but I don't see any immideately visible effects. What bonus does eating soup give me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works similar to an untouched meal that it refills your constitution fully. You can only have 1 bowl of soup per session/login.